# Error in MVC of PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

```
<?php

class Model{
    public $string;

    public function __construct(){
        echo "Constructor is called";
        $string = "MVC + PHP = Awesome!";
    }
}

class View{
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller, $model){
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output(){
        echo  "<p> The string is " . $this->model->string . "</p>";
    }
}

class Controller{
    public $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}


$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);

$view->output();
?>
```

I am trying to learn MVC framework in PHP. But I am facing this problem.
The constructor of the model is called but I dont get any output of $this->model->string in "view->output".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$string` is just a variable in a scope of a function, `$this->string` is a property.

```
class Model{
    public $string;

    public function __construct(){
        echo "Constructor is called";
        $this->string = "MVC + PHP = Awesome!"; // note change here
    }
}
```

Comment: If answer helps - feel free to __accept__ it, it raises your repo too and helps other people.